# What are the minimum number of clues to ensure a unique Futoshiki solution?

Tags: algorithm, math, sudoku, array-algorithms

We know that Sudoku requires 17 clues to ensure a unique solution. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku)
Futoshiki is a 5x5 grid, with different constraints than Sudoku has.

Is there any mathematical relation between 17 clues and a 9x9 board that I can abstract to a 5x5 board?

Why? I'm trying to write a Futoshiki app, and I'm having trouble generating puzzles with unique solutions. Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: Sudoku requires ***at least*** 17 clues before the puzzle might have a unique solution. It's easy to make a puzzle with more than 17 clues that doesn't have a unique solution.